# Remove last draw line on Canvas in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I am want to remove last draw line on Canvas in button click event.

```
this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Clear();
```

Above line remove a all draw line on canvas.I just want to remove last draw line. Any one know how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but the last line is probably also the last element of the `Children` collection. Therefore, you should be able to do:

```
if (this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Count > 0)
{
    this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Count - 1);
}
```